# Is there a MAUI Map control

Tags: maui

Is there a maui map control. If so is there a tutorial somewhere. I do not wish to use a 3rd party control, and I want to use opensteetmap. I realy do not want to use google maps.

Comment: there is not a built in Map control in the current release.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/maps?tabs=windows

Comment: Map.Default doesnt work. Default, does not exist. If you have a working example that would be great.

Comment: Did you add the correct namespace?

Comment: This one.  Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel I dont see a nuget package for that.

Comment: `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel` exists in package [Microsoft.Maui.Essentials](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-to-RC1) , did you try the [code in official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/maps?tabs=ios#using-the-map) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official Maps functionality was unfortunately cut for the current GA version. It is on the roadmap for .NET 7 which is scheduled for November.

However, that functionality will use the map which is supported on each platform, so: Apple Maps for iOS/macOS, Google Maps for Android and Bing Maps for Windows. And you specified you wanted to do OpenStreetMap.

For this there is a third-party control: [MapsUI](https://mapsui.com/). They are working on .NET MAUI support and I think they already have a test version that has .NET MAUI support.

**Update November 2022:** See the new [Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps/) package, released for .NET 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using dymaptic.GeoBlazor successfully and I can recommend it.
https://github.com/dymaptic/GeoBlazor